# Setting variable to True does not exit while False loop

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

I'm making a tic tac toe game using Python and I'm almost finished but I'm running into a problem with a while loop. Here is a shortened version of the function I use to check if a player has one.

```
def check_win(board, marker):
    win = False
    if board['A1'] == marker and board['B1'] == marker and board['C1'] == marker:
        print(f'{marker} wins!')
        win = True
    return win
```

And here it is in my code.

```
player_win = False
while player_win == False:
    # Player1's turn
    board_dict = get_and_place_marker(board_dict, player1)
    display_board(board_dict)
--> player_win = check_win(board_dict, player1)
    # Player2's turn
    board_dict = get_and_place_marker(board_dict, player2)
    display_board(board_dict)
--> player_win = check_win(board_dict, player2)
```

In the first instance of check_win(), it does assign player_win to True but it doesn't exit the loop. It goes to Player2's code and then exits when Player2 wins. What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't the first instant of player_win being assigned True exit the loop?

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: At the beginning of the while loop, it will check player_win and then execute the ENTIRE loop before checking again. You can use an if statement and a break statement to break out in the middle of the loop.

Comment: "Shouldn't the first instant of player_win being assigned True exit the loop?" Why do you believe so? Where did you learn about while loops in the first place, and what does that source tell you about when the check occurs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If player 1 wins, you are still giving player 2 a chance to make a non-winning move, in which case the loop continues. The condition is not implicitly evaluated in the middle of the loop body just because a variable in the condition changes.

Instead of making both players take a turn in each iteration, change the code so that exactly one player takes a turn, alternating between players each time.

```
from itertools import cycle

for player in cycle([player1, player2]):
    board_dict = get_and_place_marker(board_dict, player)
    if check_win(board_dict, player):
        break
```

You can then check the value of `player` to see how actually won after the loop exits.

Comment: My gut reaction was that the question shouldn't be answered, but this code solution is quite elegant. However, the answer doesn't really address OP's misconception (i.e.: "Shouldn't the first instant of player_win being assigned True exit the loop?" should be explicitly answered).